# Return a variable from a GSL multiroot function

Tags: c, gsl

Suppose I have a function that defines a set of N equations and I want to get N unknowns that set those equations to zero. The way I usually do this is to use the GSL multiroot function, for which the return is defined by an integer GLS_SUCCESS that describes whether the function can be computed. This would be an example of such a function, taken from the GSL guide.

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multiroots.h>

struct rparams
  {
    double a;
    double b;
  };

int
rosenbrock_f (const gsl_vector * x, void *params, 
              gsl_vector * f)
{
  double a = ((struct rparams *) params)->a;
  double b = ((struct rparams *) params)->b;

  const double x0 = gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
  const double x1 = gsl_vector_get (x, 1);

  const double y0 = a * (1 - x0);
  const double y1 = b * (x1 - x0 * x0);

  gsl_vector_set (f, 0, y0);
  gsl_vector_set (f, 1, y1);

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

Suppose that while I am interested in the N variables that set the values to zero, I am also interested in a variable that gets computed inside the function. For example let double c = a + b, and suppose that operation is performed inside the rosenbrock_f function. How can I access c from main? One obvious way is declaring it as a global variable. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to have the additional member of the `rparams` struct which would contain the value you want to store.

You can then modify it's value in each call to `rosenbrock_f` and you would be able to access it in your `main` function.